# Can't Install Ubuntu in UEFI mode; the live USB I made only boots in legacy mode

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, 18.04, uefi, windows-10

I have an ASUS x451CA notebook  bought for work reasons. I have Win10 installed  and I want to have a dual boot machine.

My installation of Windows 10 was completed with no issues, but when I installed Ubuntu my nightmare began.

First, my BIOS only recognizes the bootable usb I made with yumi in legacy mode; a UEFI option to boot appears, but when I select it it doesn't boot, I just get brought back to BIOS.

My notebook has no secure boot nor fast boot enabled, much less these options exist in BIOS. I disabled the legacy mode wile I'm in BIOS. It let me choose the UEFI option, but when the system restarts I'm brought back to the BIOS menu. The legacy mode install of Ubuntu runs without problems, but I'm blocked from entering Windows, the system wont find it in the GRUB menu.

Trying to solve this problem I installed boot repair, but the program says that it can fix GRUB only in UEFI mode, which I can't enable.

On my PC I have a dual boot with Win10 and Ubuntu 18.04, but in my PC I have 2 HDs where one runs a boot file separately that runs perfectly. But not in my notebook with only one HD.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Did you install Windows 10 or did system come with it? Have you updated UEFI for your model from Asus? Just run the summary report, the auto fix sometimes can create more issues.
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Comment: Are you sure that the USB stick you used was formatted with a GUID Partition Table (GPT) and not with MBR? (btw if your laptop has UEFI, it doesn't have BIOS)

Comment: How did you create the live USB drive? Which tool/method did you use? Have you tested the live USB drive in another computer?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried installing Ubuntu with UEFI Mode using Plop Boot Manager at your windows?

I tried this method to install Xubuntu on an old laptop that didn't recognize the bootable USB, then via Windows, I added this option to the menu using Plop Boot Manager, you can install it at your windows and execute it, later the computer restarts and the USB is detected via Plop Boot Manager and then you can install Ubuntu independent from mode BIOS.

My English it's not very good, then I recommend you a link that explains better how it works:

[1] How works (English Web):
https://www.plop.at/en/bootmanager/index.html

[Link to download (English Web)](https://www.plop.at/en/bootmanager/download.html).

Comment: Sorry if I misunderstood your answer. Please can you add some more details on how to do what you are suggesting? It is very vague at the moment.

Comment: Zanna I added the links in Enlgish, one for how works it and other to download it, and I try to resume what I did to install it in the old laptop.

Comment: I said it was low quality because it was a link-only answer and the link was in Spanish which most people who use this site can't read, but you have improved your answer, so I don't feel sorry that I voted to undelete it.

Comment: Yes, the link to download is in Spanish, but in the other Spanish version (Spanish stackExchange) we have English web with links to download too and it's not problem to Spanish I understand that it's not a problem neither to English. It's an improvement for you... and for my English expression but not to the essency from the original answer...